# What's with Mamet's dialogue style?

Tags: dialogue, david-mamet

If one watches a [David Mamet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Mamet) written and directed film, such as [Heist (2001)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0252503/), [Spartan (2004)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0360009/), or [House of Games (1987)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Games), it will quickly become apparent that the dialogue is, well, different. Often times very jarringly so.

According to the wiki page, "Mamet speak" is cynical, street-smart edge, precisely crafted for effect."

Why do some of his movies tend to take the Mamet style over the top? The dialogue should flow, and like in real life, parts speak over each other, yet in the movies listed, when that happens it's like the director says "now speak over him and make it OBVIOUS you are."

I'm hoping there is a real Mamet fan here who can maybe shed some light on how better to 'get' Mamet.

Comment: While I understand what you mean, I also have a hard time making out the actual question you're asking. But if phrased more clearly, this doesn't necessarily need to be closable.

Comment: I'm going to delete this (for now) and come up with a more coherent question on Mamet.

Comment: Is there any news on the revival of this question or a possible successor to it?

Comment: Not really. I'll spend some time on it to (hopefully) improve it. I still know what I wanted to ask; I'm just having trouble word-smithing it.

Comment: Yet you chose to undelete it already? So you are confident it works in this form? (If not, I'd rather wait with undeletion or people will smack it down before it's ready.)

Comment: grrr, I could not comment (to answer you) without undeleting it.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. But it seems undeletion didn't bump it anyway. So as long as you don't edit it, noone will ever notice it anyway. ;-)

Comment: You may want to remove Ronin from the list, Mamet didn't direct it and shares writing credit on it. I didn't even know he had anything to do with that movie until you asked this, though. It doesn't suffer from his overwrought dialogue, maybe because he didn't direct it. My only answer is that that's just the way he is, some writers have very distinctive styles when writing dialogue and that's his.

Comment: @DanC You're right, although I can definitely see Mamet's influence, I replaced it with Mamet's first film.

Comment: All artists have their own style. This is Mamet's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia seems to cover this quite well:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Mamet#.22Mamet_speak.22

The specific quote directly from Mamet:

> When asked how he developed his style for writing dialogue, Mamet said, "In my family, in the days prior to television, we liked to while away the evenings by making ourselves miserable, based solely on our ability to speak the language viciously. That's probably where my ability was honed."

That's simply Mamet's style. It's how he likes to write dialog.